# How to apply animations to entire Android Listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-animation, alpha

I am trying to have a Listview fade out/in under certain circumstances. I'm running into issues when running the animation, the Listview just becomes invisible and no animation is performed.

I've tried running the fade_out animation:

```
Animation out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mainActivity, R.anim.fade_out);
out.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
myListView.startAnimation(out);
```

As well as an AlphaAnimation

```
AlphaAnimation animation1 = new AlphaAnimation(1f, .5f);
animation1.setDuration(2000);
animation1.setFillAfter(false);
myListView.startAnimation(animation1)
```

and finally simply setting the alpha

```
myListView.setAlpha(.5f)
```

The best I can tell is that alpha transparencies are not supported with a list view and only values of 0 and 1 are available as alpha. I can't find any documentation confirming or denying either way.

Is there some kind of known issue with ListViews? Am I doing something wrong? Or is this some kind of limited functionality on ListViews?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my issue. emigrantdd sent me in almost the right direction, how ever there were a few problems I needed to overcome.

First I had to alter emigrantdd's code to:

```
public void viseb_gone()
{
    AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(false);

    Animation fadeout= new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
    fadeOut.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    fadeOut.setDuration(3500);

    set.addAnimation(animation);

    myListView.startAnimation(fadeOut);
    myListView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

As there was some problem with the interpolator.

The other issue I had was that the ListView I was testing on was still in a ScrollView as a part of an old design, once it was taken out it worked as was intended with the changes above.

Answer (score 0):

Just try it's.If you want to do visible :

```
 public void viseb_show(){
    AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);

    Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);

    animation.setDuration(500);
    set.addAnimation(animation);

    anim.startAnimation(animation);
    anim.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

or if non visible

```
  public void viseb_gone(){
    AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);

    Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);

    animation.setDuration(3500);
    set.addAnimation(animation);

    anim.startAnimation(animation);
    anim.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

`anim` it's you object who mast be `visible`.

Comment: Sorry this still yields the same result. For the fade_out animation, the ListView disappears for 3500 ms and then reappears (if I remove anim.setVisibility(View.GONE))